# Installing .NET 4.5.2 on development machine causes error with System.Management.Automation.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, powershell

After I installed the framework version 4.5.2 on my development machine, I opened one of my websites in VS2010.  I chose to NOT upgrade it, and have verified that the target framework is 3.5, but when I try and build, I get the error

> error BC32206: The project currently contains references to more than
>   one version of System.Core, a direct reference to version 3.5.0.0 and
>   an indirect reference (through
>   'System.Management.Automation.PSObject') to version 4.0.0.0. Change
>   the direct reference to use version 4.0.0.0 (or higher) of
>   System.Core.

For a variety of reasons, I do not want to upgrade the project to v4, and the version of System.Management.Automation.dll remains the same as before (6.1.7601.17514, dated 11/20/2010)

The problem appears when I'm running the code:

```
                For Each r As PSObject In powerShellObject.Invoke
                    Debug.Print(r.ToString)
                    returnValue += r.ToString
                Next
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your web config file:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation"
                          publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

There is a publisher policy for S.M.A.dll 1.0 that redirects it to 3.0 which is bound to .NET 4.0.